# pgAdmin - Como instalar "system tray plugin"?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, administração-postgresql

Utilizo pgAdmin 4 no Linux Mint 19.3 cinnamon.

Sempre que abro o programa, além do navegador, aparece uma pop-up dizendo:

> Note: Installing  a system tray plugin will prevent this window being
>   shown.

Já procurei, mas não consigo encontrar a que plugin ele se refere. O pgAdmin funciona normal, mas gostaria de evitar essa janela.

Imagem da janela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instalei o applet Collapsible Systray e resolveu.

Agora ao invés da janela, apenas aparece um ícone ao lado do relógio.

Comment: Acho que é o ideal pois é isso que o nome do applet promete fazer.